# VS code intellisense not working over network location

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 7/10 and I have angular 2 apps projects on remote Linux machine. I am accessing the Linux machine in windows by creating a Network Location on Windows. My problem is when I access angular 2 projects, written in typescript, vs code intellisense are not working. auto complete and angular snippets are not working. even (ctrl+space) show loading instead of suggestion.

When I try to create angular 2 project on windows, every thing is working just fine.

Comment: In the toolbar at the bottom of your screen, does it state something like "Indexing"? It could be that vscode is still busy scanning all the files of the project, which can be slow over network.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans I did not find 'indexing' at the bottom toolbar